# Fetch bot messages from bots Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that fetches previous bot messages in the channel and then deletes them. I have this code currently that deletes all messages in the channel when `!clearMessages` is entered:

```
if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
    message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        messagesDeleted = messages.array().length; // number of messages deleted

        // Logging the number of messages deleted on both the channel and console.
        message.channel.send("Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: "+messagesDeleted);
        console.log('Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: '+messagesDeleted)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while doing Bulk Delete');
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I would like the bot to only fetch messages from all bot messages in that channel, and then delete those messages.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has an [`author` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) that represents a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). Each [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) has a [`bot` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) that indicates if the user is a bot.

Using that information, we can filter out messages that are not bot messages with `messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot)`:

```
if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
    message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
        const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot);
        message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages);
        messagesDeleted = botMessages.array().length; // number of messages deleted

        // Logging the number of messages deleted on both the channel and console.
        message.channel.send("Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: " + messagesDeleted);
        console.log('Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: ' + messagesDeleted)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while doing Bulk Delete');
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much André! Also a quick question. I would like to also delete messages that start with !/./> (these messages can be from users not only bots) so I tried editing the line with the const botMessages to this: `const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot && msg.content.startsWith("!" || "." || ">"));` but that didn't work. Can you please point out where I'm going wrong and how I can fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: Another issue I noticed is that when there is only 1 bot message the bot doesn't delete the message and comes up with an DiscordAPIError, saying that you must provide at least 2-100 messages to delete. Is there a work around this?

Comment: I will open up a new question for this.

Comment: For those wanting to follow up on @qttqtt's subsequent questions, you may do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952522/discord-js-filtering-message-startswith-and-work-around-discordapierror-for-b).