# Discord.js // Filtering message startsWith and work around DiscordAPIError for bulkDelete

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

This is my current code. Credit goes to @André Dion for the help.

```
  if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
    message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
        const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot) 
        message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages);
        messagesDeleted = botMessages.array().length; // number of messages deleted

        // Logging the number of messages deleted on both the channel and console
        message.channel.send("Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: " + messagesDeleted);
        console.log('Deletion of messages successful. Total messages deleted: ' + messagesDeleted)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while doing Bulk Delete');
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

When the user enters "!clearMessages" it runs this code and deletes only messages from bots. I would like to add a feature where this also deletes messages from users that starts with !/./> (these messages can be from users not only bots),  so I tried editing the line with the const botMessages to this: `const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot && msg.content.startsWith("!" || "." || ">"));` but that didn't work. Can you please point out where I'm going wrong and how I can fix this?

Another issue I noticed is that when there is only 1 bot message the bot doesn't delete the message and comes up with an DiscordAPIError, saying that you must provide at least 2-100 messages to delete. Is there a work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: A way i thought of bypassing the error is by deleting the 2 messages together. So when a user enters ".kick @User" the bot says "kicked user." then you type in "!clearMessages" and then bot bulkDeletes the message starting with . (".kick @User") and also the message from the bot saying "kicked user." This should work since its bulk deleting 2 messages now and not 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with `const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot && msg.content.startsWith("!" || "." || ">"));`:

1. `msg.content.startsWith("!" || "." || ">")` is only going to evaluate against the first truthy statement: `"!"`. [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) only takes a single pattern, so you'll have to split that call into three calls. Let's assign the result of these checks into a single variable for convenience:

   ```
   const isCommand = msg.content.startsWith("!") || msg.content.startsWith(".") || msg.content.startsWith(">");
   ```
2. You want to filter out messages that are issued by bot users or that look like a command. Currently your logic is written so that messages that are issued by bots **and** look like a command are filtered, which is wrong (bots won't be issuing any commands). The correct check with the above additions would be:

   ```
   const botMessages = messages.filterArray(msg => {
       const isCommand = msg.content.startsWith("!") || msg.content.startsWith(".") || msg.content.startsWith(">");

       return msg.author.bot || isCommand;
   });
   ```

Correcting your filter logic should fix your `DiscordAPIError` exception but to ensure no bad calls are being issued, you should guard the `bulkDelete` invocation:

```
if (botMessages.length > 1) {
    message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages);
} else if (botMessages.length) {
    botMessages[0].delete();
} else {
    // nothing to delete
}
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks again. I have tried your code like [so - click here please,](https://pastebin.com/raw/Wau2QbzJ) and it doesn't seem to work and I get [this](http://prntscr.com/hreesk) in console Just to be clear. I want the command "!clearMessages" to delete the messages from users that start with !/>/. and also I want it to delete messages from bots. Can you please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: And I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/7rpTFgwi) to test if the discord api error bypass worked, it console logs and also sends a message saying 1 bot message has been deleted. However, it doesn't delete in the discord server, and also doesn't delete for more than 2 messages. So I changed `botMessages.length` to `botMessages.array().length` and that worked for more than 2 messages but for 1, i got [this](http://prntscr.com/hrevz8) error in console

Comment: I've [updated the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47952736/4) to account for the `Collection`/`Array` behavior. You'll otherwise need to clarify what "did not work" means. The message you're getting is a deprecation notice, not an error.