# fetch messages not retrieving messages .catch issue node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a bot for discord. I am trying to get a message content that is automatically sent to the channel upon creation. The message contains a "brawl ID" and is automatically generated through a different command which creates the channel and sends this crucial piece of information to the channel once created. The message I am trying to get the content of will ALWAYS be the first message sent in the channel. I had this working originally with just a message filter looking at the first and last messages sent by the bot, but once the bot sent a few messages, it kept fetching the wrong message, so I came up with this...

```
  if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 1}).then(messages => {
const botMessages = messages.filter(message => { 
const startingMessage = message.content.includes("Player A"); 
}).catch(err => {
console.log('Error while fetching starting message!');
console.log(err);

console.log(startingMessage)

if (startingMessage.length > 1) {
  const startingMessage = message.author.bot && startingMessage
} else {
  message.channel.send("No brawl initiation message found!")
}
var brawlID = startingMessage.content.slice(-8) // slices off last 8 characters which is the brawlID  I need (refer to screenshot linked above)

console.log(`Brawl ID is ${brawlID}`)
```

The message I am trying to target is [this](https://i.gyazo.com/c6af54647aabbbc1707fd74df48ffd1e.png). I am getting errors to the console of

> (node:20820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
>   messages.filter(...).catch is not a function

and

> (node:20820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I know there's something up with my .catch placement, because I have it, yet it tells me it hasn't been handled correctly. I can't get the message by ID, because a different command automatically makes the channel and sends the message.

Thanks in advance for the help, or alternate ways to fetch only the first message sent to the channel (and not find it via message ID).

FYI: I've been looking at these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951918/fetch-bot-messages-from-bots-discord-js) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952522/discord-js-filtering-message-startswith-and-work-around-discordapierror-for-b) before posting this question.

Comment: The outermost `if`-block, `messages.filter`, and `catch` are missing their corresponding block/function closing statements. (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)) for example))
There are other problems related to asynchrony and [scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that will prevent this program from producing the desired result, however.

Comment: To elaborate on the scoping and async problems:

Using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) creates a block-scoped variable, making it unavailable in outer scopes, something the original example depends on.

Comment: And by using a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to create the `const` variables, the promise will only start running after the code that depends on the variables the promise creates is run. To clarify, everything below and including `console.log(startingMessage)` would run first.

Comment: Also lets not forget messages.filter(...) is not async so catch doesnt work there

Comment: @antino same question to PLASMA chicken too. How would I go about fixing this then? I understand about the block statement, but as for the other issues mentioned, I am unsure how to go about fixing it. Is there a way to fetch ONLY the first message in a channel, regardless of who posts it? That is all I really need. The bot will always post the needed statement before any other user has the time to comment. Maybe grabbing only pinned messages and when the needed message is posted, the bot somehow autopins it? Is that possible?