# Await is only valid in async function for bulkDelete

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord

I'm coding a Discord bot using Discord.js and i'm trying to make a .clear command, to clear messages. The problem is that I can't delete the messages because i'm getting a `await is only valid in async function` when trying to use bulkDelete. I'm coding that in the `bot.on('message', msg => {` section. Here is my code:

```
if (msg.content.startsWith('.clear')) {
    if(msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
      const args = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1);
      const amount = args.join(' ');
      if(!amount) {
        const noNumbers = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setDescription(':no_entry: Vous n\'avez pas précisé combien de messages devraient être supprimés !')
        msg.channel.send(noNumbers)
      }
      if(isNaN(amount)) {
        const notNumber = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setDescription(':no_entry: Ce paramètre n\'est pas un nombre !')
        msg.channel.send(notNumber)
      }
      if(amount > 100) {
        const tooMuch = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setDescription(':no_entry: Vous ne pouvez pas supprimer plus de 100 messages à la fois !')
        msg.channel.send(tooMuch)
      }
      if(amount < 1) {
        const tooLess = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setDescription(':no_entry: Vous ne pouvez pas supprimer moins d\'un message !')
        msg.channel.send(tooLess)
      }
      else {
          await msg.channel.messages.fetch({limit: amount}).then(messages => {
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages)        
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks ! (Don't mind about the embed descriptions, I'm french)

Comment: Why are you using `await` at all when you already use `then` syntax?

Comment: @Bergi if his returned promise, itself, returns a new promise, this is legit. However, you're right, might as well just chain another then. I actually think this function doesn't need to use async await. If it was returning a value it may be easier to read, but you're basically deferring action until after the message fetch is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Delete my answer because @Christopher Stevens got there first. Just to expand:

Using await essentially lets you pause execution of a function when your expression returns a promise. The catch is that the calling function needs to be async

Comment: When I try this, I get another error : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.channel.messages.fetch is not a function`

Comment: @KrystStalin I believe that means that you've progressed further (async issue resolved) and now have a separate issue to work out. For example, you may want to try `msg.channel.fetchMessages()` instead of `msg.channel.messages.fetch()` (just guessing based on [Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951918/fetch-bot-messages-from-bots-discord-js), could be dated)